# How to add React Native support layer inside my iOS Native SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

What I am trying is to add a react native layer inside my iOS SDK it self to support React Native so that If some React native app uses my SDK they cal APIs directly with out they adding any layers for it.

Answer (score 0):

To give support that React native can use your Native SDK you have to create RN bridge between Native module and JS as follow:

> React-native-aaplication ----> JS wrapper -----> Native code
>   Wrapper(Swift/Objective c) ----> SDK

React-native application layer would call JS wrapper and then, JS layer would call method written in native code Wrapper which interact with you Native SDK.

From below link you will understand how to use Native module:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

How to create RN bridge go through below links:

https://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-achieve-react-native-and-ios-bridging/#
https://hackernoon.com/first-experiences-with-react-native-bridging-an-ios-native-module-for-app-authentication-7a20b7180fc9